# Get content of html elements and repeat it in some places of the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I´m making a pricing plan with Bootstrap 3.0, you can check it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ytrcLg5m/8/

The problem is that I have this fragment of code in one-column in desktop version:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="row pg-item ">
        <div class="col-md-10 pg-item-desc">Price</div>
        <span class="pg-info">
        <i class="icon-info icon-xsmall" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Te enviamos todos los años nuestro catálogo actualizado gratuitamente"></i>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li class="row pg-item ">
        <div class="col-md-10 pg-item-desc">Catalog</div>
        <span class="pg-info">
        <i class="icon-info icon-xsmall" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Te enviamos todos los años nuestro catálogo actualizado"></i>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li class="row pg-item ">
        <div class="col-md-10 pg-item-desc">Free Shipping</div>
        <span class="pg-info"><i class="icon-info icon-xsmall" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Te enviamos gratuitamente a tu negocio lo que nos pidas con servicio 24h. Sólo válido para servicios y productos personalizados, no válido para pedidos de material."></i></span>
    </li>
    <li class="row pg-item pg-item-lg">
        <div class="col-md-10 pg-item-desc">Outlet</div>
        <span class="pg-info"><i class="icon-info icon-xsmall" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Todos los lunes tendrás acceso a una oferta limitada de hasta un 50% de descuento en productos concretos. También dispondrás de carteles para que los anuncies en tu negocio."></i></span>
    </li>
    <li class="row pg-item ">
        <div class="col-md-10 pg-item-desc">Material shop</div>
        <span class="pg-info"><i class="icon-info icon-xsmall" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tendrás acceso a una tienda exclusiva de material y producto blanco en general, por si quieres fabricarte algo tú mismo."></i></span>
    </li>
    <li class="row pg-item ">
        <div class="col-md-10 pg-item-desc">Pick points</div>
        <span class="pg-info"><i class="icon-info icon-xsmall" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Saldrás en el mapa de distribuidores y los particulares que compren por la web podrán elegir tu tienda como punto de recogida, generándote comisiones de venta."></i></span>
    </li>
    <li class="row pg-item ">
        <div class="col-md-10 pg-item-desc">Development photos</div>
        <span class="pg-info"><i class="icon-info icon-xsmall" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Te recogemos tus carretes y formatos físicos para ofrecerte todos los servicios de laboratorio: revelado analógico, digital, APS, Blanco y negro, diapositivas, etc."></i></span>
    </li>
    <li class="row pg-item ">
        <div class="col-md-10 pg-item-desc">Credit account</div>
        <span class="pg-info"><i class="icon-info icon-xsmall" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Pide todo lo que quieras, y al final de mes, te lo facturamos todo junto. Para que hagas los pedidos de la forma más rápida y ágil posible"></i></span>
    </li>
    <li class="row pg-item ">
        <div class="col-md-10 pg-item-desc">Muestrario</div>
        <span class="pg-info"><i class="icon-info icon-xsmall" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Incluye un lote de productos preseleccionados para que tus clientes puedan ver y tocar."></i></span>
    </li>
    <li class="row pg-item pg-item-lg-when-md">
        <div class="col-md-10 pg-item-desc">Software</div>
        <span class="pg-info"><i class="icon-info icon-xsmall" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Si dispones de kioscos táctiles en tu negocio, un técnico te instalará nuestro software de kiosco para que sean tus propios clientes quien hagan los pedidos. También incluye formación y soporte técnico."></i></span>
    </li>
    <li class="row pg-item pg-item-lg">
        <div class="col-md-10 pg-item-desc">Lotes estacionales</div>
        <span class="pg-info"><i class="icon-info icon-xsmall" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Varias veces al año podrás tener acceso a publicidad y muestrario de nuevos productos ideales según la época: día de los enamorados, navidades, vuelta al cole..."></i></span>
    </li>
    <li class="row pg-item pg-item-lg">
        <div class="col-md-10 pg-item-desc">Custom solutions</div>
        <span class="pg-info"><i class="icon-info icon-xsmall" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Nos adaptamos a ti, para cubrir todo lo que necesites: logística avanzada, integración de software, etc."></i></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In a mobile devices I want show this column about three times, one for each plan, and I want to add their corresponding icons fa-check and fa-times.

The problem is that I have to repeat this three times, **is there any way to do with javascript?**

I just want to have a column on mobile devices and repeat three times.

Like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be you can first check if you are in a touch device:
    isTouchDevice: function() {
       return 'ontouchstart' in window  || navigator.maxTouchPoints;
    }

then repeat your code by cloning it using .clone(); and .append()